# Ruby on Rails Charset issue: Euro logo turns to ‚Ç¨

Tags: ruby-on-rails, character-encoding

I am using Ruby 1.8.7 and rails 2.3.5

Say for example in my controller I have this code:

```
def test
  send_data "€", :type => 'text/plain;',
                 :filename => 'test.txt'
end
```

(the example is on mac) When the file is opened with TextMate, it shows Euro logo correctly, but when viewed by pressing "space" button or using TextEdit, that Euro logo shows as ‚Ç¨

What should I do to make it show as Euro logo instead?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

**HELP!!**

**UPDATE**

I have made it work on my local version (Mac OSX machine) using:

```
Iconv.new('MacRoman', 'UTF-8').iconv(currency_code)
```

But on my public linux machine, it returns:

```
Iconv::InvalidEncoding (invalid encoding ("MacRoman", "UTF-8"))
```

I guess it has something to do with me having to install MacRoman encoding on my linux machine? How do I do that?

**Update 2**

I did not find the answer I expected, so we had to change TXT format to HTML, where you can specify its UTF-8.

Comment: Seems to me that it's working just fine, only TextEdit is interpreting the file using the wrong encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TextEdit is using MacRoman to interpret the file instead of UTF-8. So, not your bug.

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to tell TextEdit that the file is UTF-8 so it can interpret it that way somehow?

Comment: I have no idea. I usually stick to Geany.

Comment: But you can write Euro logo in TextEdit so it is impossible if you cannot do that through ruby code

Comment: Hi, oh I think I started to get it now, thank you! Wondering if you could add a reference how to change outputted file (is it possible with string as well?) encoding to "MacRoman"?

Comment: This looks promising, just reverse the arguments to `.new()`: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/49891#15674

Comment: Hi, This almost works! in my local it works, but in online version it returned Iconv::InvalidEncoding (invalid encoding ("MacRoman", "UTF-8")) any idea? Thanks!

Comment: We finally changed the specs to use HTML instead. Thanks for your help so far :)

Answer (score 0):

from http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-10332226-263.html

Go to the menu named TextEdit. The second item is "Preferences." Select it. The window that opens has two tabs" "New Document" and "Open and Save." In each case, you can make changes to TextEdit's default settings.

Read more: http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-10332226-263.html#ixzz172mnmbLl

Comment: I do not think users of my application will bother to do this so a preferable way is to change encoding of outputted file, which I have no idea how to...